# How to insert custom mines in a minesweeper mini-game?

Tags: c, minesweeper

I'm making a mini-minesweeper game, and it has multiple options. But the one I am having trouble with is when the user enters the plant text, followed by the X and Y coordinates, the program must place a mine. If, in the coordinates passed by the user, there is a mine in off state (*), the program must change its state to armed(.). And if there is a mine in the coordinates passed by the user, the program should only continue without any error message.
The blank spaces are represented by _

```c
//  main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define map_SIZE 25
void mapa(void);
void printUsermap(void);
void readf(void);
void bombmaker (void);

void mapa(void){
    int column, row;
    char umap[map_SIZE][map_SIZE];

    for(column = 0; column < map_SIZE; column++)
        for(row = 0; row < map_SIZE; row++)
            umap[column][row] = '_';
}

void printUsermap(){
    int column, row;
    char umap[map_SIZE][map_SIZE];
    system("cls");

    for(column = 0; column < map_SIZE ; column++)
    {
        for(row = 0; row < map_SIZE; row++)
        {
            printf("%c", umap[column][row]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
        
    }
void bombmaker (){
    char map[map_SIZE][map_SIZE];
    char final_map[map_SIZE][map_SIZE];
    char mines = '\0';
    int i=0, j=0;
    if( map[i][j] != '*')
            {
                map[i][j] = '*';
                final_map[i][j] = map[i][j];
                mines++;
            }
}

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    char option[128];
    char mines = '\0';
    char map[map_SIZE][map_SIZE];
    char final_map[map_SIZE][map_SIZE];

// MENU
  printf("+-----------------------------------------------------\n");

  printf(" read <filename>     - read input file\n show                - show the mine map\n trigger <x> <y>     - trigger mine at <x> <y>\n plant <x> <y>       - place armed mine at <x> <y>\n export <filename>   - save file with current map\n quit                - exit program\n sos                 - show menu\n ");

  printf("+-----------------------------------------------------\n");
    
    
  do{
    printf(">");
    scanf ("%s", option);

//there are the other options first(not finished yet)

 else if (strcmp(option, "plant")==0)
    {
      scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
      if (x >= 25 || y >= 25){
      fprintf(stdout, "Invalid coordinate\n");
      }
      else if (map[x][y] == '_'){
      map[x][y] = '.';
      final_map[x][y] = map[x][y];
      mines++;
      }

      else if (map[x][y] == '*'){
      map[x][y] = '.';
      final_map[x][y] = map[x][y];
      mines++;
      }
while (strcmp(option,"quit")!=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what exactly do you have problems with? Besides:  All your functions are working o a function local map, so that code has no effect. Why don't they work on a global map or a map passed as parameter?

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
            if (x >= 25 || y >= 25)`  this fails to catch values < 0.  should always check the returned value from the `scanf()` family of functions to assure  the operation was successful.  Note: The `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input format conversion' specifiers.  Therefore suggest: `if( scanf( "%d %d", &x, &y ) != 2 ) { handle error }  if (x < 0 || x >= 25 || y < 0 || y >= 25) { handle error )`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);`  always prompt the user so the user knows what is expected for input.  This includes the limits of 0 and 24

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) In general, always include the optional opening/closing braces around the body of a `while()` or `if()` code block

Comment: variables declared inside a function, on the stack, disappear when the function exits.  Suggest using the `umap[][]` (and similar declarations declared in `main()` and passing the address of those arrays to the sub functions as parameters

Comment: regarding: `scanf ("%s", option);` This allows the user to input enough characters to overflow the input buffer. Always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer. 1 less than, because the %s specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input. This avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior\.  suggest: `scanf ("%127s", option);`

Comment: it is best for a multidimensional array to have the `row` as the first dimension and the `column` as the second dimension

Comment: regarding statements like: `int row, column;`  and `for( column = 0; column < map_SIZE ; column++ )
    {
        for( row = 0; row < map_SIZE; row++ )
        {
            printf("%c", umap[ column ][ row ] );
        }
        printf("\n");`  It is always best to limit the scope of local variables.  Suggest: 1) remove the declarations for `row` and `column`  2) for( *int* column = 0; column < map_SIZE ; column++ )
    {
        for( *int* row = 0; row < map_SIZE; row++ )
        {
            printf("%c", umap[ column ][ row ] );
        }
        printf("\n");